# Devexpress report header band causes the table in the detail band in the first page to spread on the next page

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, xtrareport

In Devexpress report, the report header band causes the XRTable in the detail band in the first page to spread on the next page and then breaks the page at the same height of the report header band leaving the page almost empty except of some rows.

Any tip how to solve this problem, thanks.

Comment: Check this screenshot and notice the second page how is it rendered https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1R_dTpcwmxARkROVDk5dy1Kamc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole report is being initialized dynamically and the problem was solved by giving height to the XRTable which is being added to the report header band before adding it to the band.